# Change thymeleaf roles at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

If a have a table with secured html tags from a view and roles like this:

1. view_1,resource_1, role_1
2. view_1,resource_1, role_2
3. view_1,resource_2, role_2
4. view_1,resource_2, role_3

Is there a way to secured those html tags using thymeleaf security without hardcoding the roles?

For example:

Hardcoded for view_1, resource_1:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('role_1','role_2')">...</div>
```

What a want for view_1, resource_1:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(ROLES_FROM_DATABASE)">...</div>
```

Comment: why not. pass the ```ROLES_FROM_DATABASE``` model to your view remember it should be array

Comment: I've tried that with no results because it would be something like this `<div sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(''th:text="${ROLES_FROM_DATABASE}"'')">...</div>`

Comment: how about ```sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(ROLES_FROM_DATABASE)">...</div>```?

Comment: Don’t use roles. Use authorities and see roles as a collection of authorities. That way you can configure as many roles (or groups as they are called in Spring Security terms) and have still the same authority one needs to access a page.